# How to quickly navigate/jump between functions on emacs?

Tags: c, linux, windows, emacs

How to quickly navigate/jump between functions on emacs? I'm looking for a way to jump quickly to functions on emacs. I'm using the emacs search to do it,but it's too slow and fail. For example,I need to make sure to type a string that will not match to function prototype or function call. I need to include the type of function and begging of parameters type to it.. and depending to coding syntax style used in the program,it's hard/inviable to do. 
What exactly I'm looking for: something that I type just the function name and jump to begging of it. My current language is C on linux. But if there's such feature to another programming languages and platforms,please show me too. Will be very appreciated.

*Please: don't suggest "use an IDE" I'm fine with emacs.*

Comment: You may want to search on integrating cscope with Emacs.

Comment: Cross-referencing with similar/duplicate questions: * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071919/how-can-i-best-do-source-code-browsing-inside-emacs
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922526/tags-for-emacs-relationship-between-etags-ebrowse-cscope-gnu-global-and-exhu
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440613/code-navigation-in-vim-and-emacs
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598351/emacs-etags-and-using-emacs-as-an-ide
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124567/tags-in-emacs-with-a-large-codebase
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943705/gnu-emacs-equivalent-of-func-menu

Comment: Use `helm-semantic-or-iemnu`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`M-x imenu` lets you jump to functions in the same file.  I have bound it to Super-i for easy access.

Comment: Hmm. Seems imenu only searches the current open buffers. Any info on configuring it to search the whole project?

Comment: I'll advice to combine imenu with ido-goto-symbol or the helm mode. This way you have just to type few letters from the name of the function to jump to it in the current buffer.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using `cscope` integrated into Emacs, and it works really well for searching for functions, variables etc and jumping around between them.

Edit:
in .emacs (or .xemacs/init.el) I have:

```
(require 'xcscope)
(setq cscope-do-not-update-database t)
```

Then I just manually run cscope on the source files as needed (for the Linux kernel, `make cscope`, which also works on many other large projects).

Comment: Could you post your `cscope` config? I'm still trying to figure out how to configure it for efficient and streamlined workflow...

Comment: Yes, edit with config posted...

Comment: Wait... that's all? Now I feel kinda stupid... :-)

Answer (score 3):

As already suggested by others I also use `Imenu` exclusively to navigate in the buffer. I find it very useful to do that by having `ido` interface for Imenu. here is my config for `ido-imenu`. (this is slightly modified version from the function you find it emacswiki page)

```lisp
(defun ido-imenu ()
  "Update the imenu index and then use ido to select a symbol to navigate to.
Symbols matching the text at point are put first in the completion list."
  (interactive)
  (imenu--make-index-alist)
  (let ((name-and-pos '())
        (symbol-names '()))
    (flet ((addsymbols
            (symbol-list)
            (when (listp symbol-list)
              (dolist (symbol symbol-list)
                (let ((name nil) (position nil))
                  (cond
                   ((and (listp symbol) (imenu--subalist-p symbol))
                    (addsymbols symbol))

                   ((listp symbol)
                    (setq name (car symbol))
                    (setq position (cdr symbol)))

                   ((stringp symbol)
                    (setq name symbol)
                    (setq position
                          (get-text-property 1 'org-imenu-marker symbol))))

                  (unless (or (null position) (null name))
                    (add-to-list 'symbol-names name)
                    (add-to-list 'name-and-pos (cons name position))))))))
      (addsymbols imenu--index-alist))
    ;; If there are matching symbols at point, put them at the beginning
    ;; of `symbol-names'.
    (let ((symbol-at-point (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
      (when symbol-at-point
        (let* ((regexp (concat (regexp-quote symbol-at-point) "$"))
               (matching-symbols
                (delq nil (mapcar
                           (lambda (symbol)
                             (if (string-match regexp symbol) symbol))
                           symbol-names))))
          (when matching-symbols
            (sort matching-symbols (lambda (a b) (> (length a) (length b))))
            (mapc
             (lambda (symbol)
               (setq symbol-names (cons symbol (delete symbol symbol-names))))
             matching-symbols)))))
    (let* ((selected-symbol (ido-completing-read "Symbol? " symbol-names))
           (position (cdr (assoc selected-symbol name-and-pos))))
      (push-mark)
      (if (overlayp position)
          (goto-char (overlay-start position))
        (goto-char position)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-i") 'ido-imenu)
```

And I can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-i</kbd> in many number of languages modes that support `imenu`

Comment: This is a cool solution!

Comment: This is a very good solution. Another alternative is to enable the helm mode this way you get the same functionality by default without the need of extra lisp code.